# Meaning of すきっとした

Tags: grammar, words, adverbs, literature

> 白い十字架がたって、それはもう凍った北極の雲で鋳たといったらいいか、**すきっとした**金いろの円光をいただいて.

From  銀河鉄道の夜. What is exactly the meaning of すきっとした. Also what is いったらいいか? Maybe らしい?

Answer (score 5):

すきっと is actually a dictionary word — for example 大辞林 has

> **すきっと**
> （副）<sub>スル</sub>
>
> すっきりしたさま。さっぱりしたさま。 「頭が－する」 「 －した気分になる」

It's an adverb for する (sometimes also called a *to*-adverb) which describes something being clear/clutter-free (and the positive effect this has on one's mind). I guess you can associate it to 空く【すく】 or 透く【すく】.

---

といったらいいか is just

- と quoting particle
- 言ったら *tara* form of 言う
- いい = 良い
- か question particle

and is similar to the function of と[い]{言}うか, which I guess can be analyzed as a rhetorical question and literally means

> should one say [...] or [...]

Here, the writer is trying to depict their impression with imagery, saying

> …白い十字架がたって、それはもう凍った北極の雲で鋳たといったらいいか、すきっとした金いろの円光をいただいて、しずかに永久に立っているのでした。
>
> [There] a white cross stood, cast from the frozen Arctic clouds one might say, and crowned with a clear/pure golden halo, and it stood there silently and eternally.

(As always, this is a working translation, kept close to the structure of the original sentence, so that it be easy to see how the parts correspond.)

Answer (score 3):

[Atop the island, on a plateau, stood a cross, silent and eternal, so dazzling and white that it might have been cast from frozen Arctic clouds, crowned with a pure halo of gold.](https://www.cyberspace.org/~n8rxs/chapt7.htm)

Goo辞書 and コトバンク both have the same definition for すきっとした:

> ［副］(スル)すがすがしいさま。さっぱりした感じがするさま。「すきっとした気分」「すきっとした身なり」

Included on the コトバンク entry is the additional information that it is equivalent to　すっきりした and さっぱりした.　Plain; light; refreshed are some of the main English translations. In the translation above, 'pure' seems an adequate representation.

～と言ったらいいか expresses that words cannot suffice or that one does not have the confidence that they can provide adequate words to describe what they are seeing. In other words, 'what might be described as'. Hence the 'might have been' in the translation.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the context, but スキっとする is to be/feel clear or refreshed.

Also depends on the context, but いったらいいか could be 行ったらいいか or 言ったらいいか. It sounds like a sentence fragment (e.g., どこに行ったらいいか分からなかった, 何を言ったらいいか分からなかった, etc.). Assuming it's 言う, 言ったらいい means "should say." It's the same as 言えばいい. 彼は何を言ったらいいか分からなかった is "he didn't know what he should say."